# How to translate form select laravel 5 short way

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a shorter way instead of the foreach?

```
$salutation = Salutation::lists('salutation', 'id');

$newsalutation = array();
foreach( $salutation as $key => $salute ){
    $newsalutation[$key] = trans('messages.'.$salute.'');
}
```

Messages.php

```
return [   
    'mr'=> 'mr.',
    'mrs'=> 'mr.',
];
```

Form

```
{{ Form::select('salutation_id', $salutation, old('salutation_id'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @FrankMartin PHP Version 5.6.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```php
$salutation = Salutation::lists('salutation', 'id')->map(function ($salutation) {
    return trans(sprintf('messages.%s', $salutation));
})->toArray();
```

Comment: And the translation?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really make that much difference but:

```
$salutation = Salutation::lists('salutation', 'id');
$salutation->transform(function ($item, $key) {
    return trans('messages.'.$item);
})->toArray();
```